# How to prove that a commitment hides the decryption of an ElGamal ciphertext?

Tags: signature, zero-knowledge-proofs, elgamal-encryption, secret-sharing, commitments

I've decided to remove a previous unanswered question of mine and break it down into smaller pieces so it's not such a loaded question.

For this question I need to prove that I've committed to a number, and that same number is the plaintext of some ElGamal ciphertext, without opening the commitment or decrypting the ciphertext. I have a start, as in I know a proof that is supposed to work, but I need some help.

### Definitions

I have standard ElGamal encryption wherein plaintext $v$ is encrypted as $u$ as follows: $$E(v)=u=(y_{1},y_{2})=(\alpha^{r},v\beta^{r}) \mod p$$ where $p$ is a safe prime $p=2q+1$, $q$ is also a large prime, and $r \in _{R}\mathbb{Z}_{p}$.

I also have a commitment scheme that is very similar to Pedersen commitment, called Fujisaki-Okamoto commitment. Given large safe primes $p^{\prime}$ and $q$, $N=p^{\prime}q$; public elements $g$ and $h$ are both generators in $G$, a large cyclic subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^{*}_{N}$ (such that $\log_{g}h$ and $\log_{h}g$ are intractable). I commit to $v$ with $$C=g^{v}h^{r^{\prime}}\mod N$$ where $r^{\prime} \in _{R}\mathbb{Z}_{N}$.

### Problem

I need to prove that $v$ is encrypted in $u$ and committed in $C$. My understanding based on what I'm trying to implement is that I need to prove knowledge of $v$, $r$, and $r^{\prime}$ such that $$y_{1}=\alpha^{r} \mod p$$ $$y_{2}=v\beta^{r} \mod p$$ $$ C=g^{v}h^{r^{\prime}} \mod N$$

I know that Markus Stadler has a proof of verifiable encryption of discrete logarithms in [Publicly Verifiable Secret Sharing](http://www.ubilab.org/publications/print_versions/pdf/sta96.pdf) §3.3. This uses a double discrete logarithm proof to show that a ciphertext $u=(y_{1},y_{2})$ encrypts the discrete logarithm of a public element $V=g^v$. The protocol I am trying to implement says this proof will work, but it does not tell me *how* to use it in this context, just that I *can*. It seems straightforward to me except for two things, which I've listed in order of importance:

1. I don't just have some public element $V=g^v$. I have a public element $C=g^{v}h^{r^{\prime}}=Vh^{r^{\prime}}$. This product, obviously vital to the commitment scheme, seems to make it so that I can't use Stadler's PVSS scheme. But the paper insists that it works, so I'm obviously just missing something.
2. In Stadler's paper he defines ElGamal encryption as $(\alpha^{r},v^{-1}\beta^{r})$ rather than $(\alpha^{r},v\beta^{r})$. I've never seen it done this way and the protocol I'm implementing does it the normal way. But Stadler's proof seems to depend on that modular inverse. Can I use this proof without changing the encryption scheme?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Sorry, no, I did not.

Comment: For question1: you can produce a proof that $V$ and $C$ has the same opening $v$ by proving that you know the discrete log of $\frac{C}{V} = h^{r'}$. (if the openings are not the same this is not possible to know).

Comment: see this question for details https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/74246/zero-knowledge-proof-for-opening-of-pedersen-commit-and-discrete-logarithm